# PHP <==> MySQL; storing Cyrillic / Scandinavian characters in the database

Tags: php, mysqli, utf-8, character-encoding, cyrillic

There are so many threads dedicated to this topic, that I feel silly having to ask this.

But, I'm at a total loss as to what the problem could be.

I am trying to insert special characters (cyrillic, scandinavian, etc) into a MySQL database, via PHP (html) form.

Characters like :  Ä,Ö,Å, as well as russian alphabets, etc.

Based on previous threads in this forum, I have tried all the following (inserted right after the MySQL database-connection string) :

```
    mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```

This didn't work, so I tried the following :

```
    mysqli_query("set names 'utf8'");
    mysqli_query("set charset 'utf8'");
```

These are not recommended by PHP.  But, I tried them anyway, but still no luck.

(All my databases, tables, and columns are collated as :  **UTF8_general_ci**)

In addition, all my html forms have the following :

```
  <meta charset="utf-8">
```

So, I'm at a complete loss as to what I'm doing wrong.  Once the data is sent to the database, it shows up (in the database itself) as rubbish characters  (question marks, and other hieroglyphics).

However, the funny thing is :

(a)  When I view the data on my website, it displays correctly;

(b)  When the data is sent within the body of an email, it also displays correctly

So..........why is it not displaying correctly within the database itself ??

Comment: did you tried `utf8_encode($str)` before send it to database? if it _does_ work (proper text in database, not on page), try to add `AddDefaultCharset utf-8` to yours `.htaccess` and also save all yours `php` files in utf-8 encoding (it'simportant!)

Comment: What is "within the database"? Did you look at the raw storage with a hexeditor? Or did you mean a database viewer? If so, which? What settings does *it* exhibit? Tried other database browsers?

Comment: Did you set the meta tag on the website to work correctly?

Comment: Thanx,  but I fail to see what "browsers" and "websites" have to do with this, seeing as (as I stated) :  the display is faulty only when viewed in the database. When the data is extracted FROM the database, and viewed elsewhere (web browser, email text, etc), it shows as it should.

Answer (score 5):

When dealing with specific charset (like UTF-8), it's important that the entire line of code is set to the same charset. Below are a few pointers how to follow this.

- ALL attributes must be set to ut8 (collation is *NOT* the same as charset in the database)
- You should save the document itself as UTF-8 (If you're using Notepad++, it's *Format*  -> *Convert to UFT-8* (or UTF-8 w/o BOM), there's a difference - both or either may work for you)
- The header in both PHP and HTML should be set to UTF-8:

  - HTML: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`
  - PHP: `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`
- Upon connecting to the databse, set the charset ti UTF-8, like this:
  `$connection->set_charset("utf8");` (directly after connecting)
- Also make sure your database and tables are set to UTF-8, you can do that by this query (in the database, need only be done once):

  `ALTER DATABASE databasename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;`
  `ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;`

Remember that EVERYTHING needs to be set to UFT-8 charcode. If something can be set to UFT-8 (or another charset, check the PHP-docs (php.net)), it should be set to the same charset as everything else.

Comment: Thanks, for the response, Qirel.  

shouldn't that be :  utf8_general_ci,  instead of "unicode" ?

As I mentioned earlier :  my database (and tables, and attributes) are already set to a collation :  utf8_general_ci

Comment: Well, as I said above, `collation` != `charset`. But whether you use `utf8_general_ci` or `utf8_unicode_ci` shouldn't make much of a difference, the key thing is that it's utf8 (there are only minor differences between `general`, `unicode`, `danish` etc..). However you should set thins so everything is the *same* .

Comment: Thank you! $connection->set_charset("utf8"); this worked!

Answer (score 0):

> (a) When I view the data on my website, it displays correctly;
>
> (b) When the data is sent within the body of an email, it also displays correctly

This means data is correctly stored in the db, when you get the output is the same like the input, logically correct?

The other question is: How are you looking into the database, which kind of client are you using?

PHPMyAdmin, SomeDesktop Client.. The problem will be there.. because the data is stored right.. seems so ;)

Comment: Yes, I am using PHPMyAdmin to view my database, and its contents;

Comment: Ok, try to install some SQL Client and access the database.. Don't know which OS you are on, but there are a lot of opensource software or freeware for this.. like SequelPro for OSX.. There is http://www.heidisql.com/ for Windows I guess, didn't tried it.